# I can't figure out how to use double pointers

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

I'm trying to use dynamic memory allocation but I can't figure out pointers.
I got the first part down.

```
void addtext(char **wordarray)
{
    char word[N];
    char endword[N] = "end";
    int i=0;
    int words=0;
    while (scanf("%19s", word), strcmp(word,endword))
    {
        words++;
        wordarray = realloc(wordarray, words*sizeof(char *));
        wordarray[words-1] = malloc (N*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(wordarray[words-1], word);
    }


    for (i=0; i<words; i++)
        printf("%s\n", wordarray[i]);
    return ;
}
```

But I'm having trouble when I try to call the same array in a different function.

```
void savetext(char **wordarray)
{
    FILE *savedtext;
    int i=0;
    savedtext = fopen("Saved Text.txt","wt");
    while(wordarray[i][0]!= '\0')
    {
        fputs(wordarray[i++],savedtext);
        fputs(" ",savedtext);

    }

    return ;
}
```

My main function looks something like this:

```
int main (void)
{
    char **wordarray;
    addtext(wordarray);
    savetext(wordarray);
    return 0;
}
```

The second part of the code is obviously wrong, but I'm not sure how to exactly how to call those functions. My previous program didn't use any memory allocation so I didn't bother with pointers.I'm really new to c so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `double *` is a "double pointer". `char **` is a "pointer to pointer to char".

Comment: `wordarray` is uninitialized, so `realloc(wordarray)` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy. Well, you have two big problems.

First, you never allocated the first `wordarray`. At the very least `malloc` it once:

```
char **wordarray = malloc(1);
```

Or even better, use `malloc` instead of `realloc` the first time (and initialize `wordarray` with 0!):

```
wordarray = wordarray ? realloc(wordarray, words * sizeof(char *)) 
    : malloc(words * sizeof(char *));
```

Second, your `addtext` function is receiving a copy of this array, and doing stuff with it. Whatever the stuff is, it won't be saved in your `wordarray` outside, in `main`. What you need to do is pass a pointer to the array in your function, and edit the `main` object through that:

```
void addtext(char ***wordarray)
{
    // ...
}
```

And lastly, you have some very big performance problems, allocating buffers so often. Use a proper growing vector implementation, or if you insist on writing your own at the very least grow it by doubling the size, or even better count the words and allocate the correct size.

Also your `end` string is arbitrarily allocated of length `N`, whatever that is. You don't need that, you already know the length. In fact the string is already in the read-only section of your binary, simply get a pointer to it:

```
const char *endword = "end";
```

Comment: This statement wordarray = wordarray ? realloc(wordarray, words * sizeof(char *)) 
    : malloc(words * sizeof(char *)); does not make a sense.

Comment: That is quite the strong statement, perhaps you mean it doesn't make sense to you? Is there anything in particular you don't understand on that line?

Comment: I said what I wanted to say.:) The statement as it is written does not make a sense. The function realloc behaves as the function malloc when a null pointer is used as an argument. So to use the conditional operator does not make a sense.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the program has undefined behavior at least because the pointer `wordarray` was not initialized and has an indeterminate value

```
char **wordarray;
```

and this indeterminate value is used in a call of the function `realloc` in the function `addtext`

```
wordarray = realloc(wordarray, words*sizeof(char *));
```

Moreover the pointer is passed to the function `addtext` by value. That is the function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer. So changing the copy does not influence on the value stored in the original pointer. The original pointer in main will stay unchanged.

You need to pass the pointer by reference through a pointer to it.

Another problem of the function is that the number of stored strings will not be known outside the function `addtext`. You need at least append the array with a null pointer that will be used as a sentinel value.

Also this condition in the while loop within the function `savetext`

```
while(wordarray[i][0]!= '\0')
```

does not make a sense because within the function `addtext`  you stop entering strings when the user will enter the string `"end"`.

```
while (scanf("%19s", word), strcmp(word,endword))
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So it is not necessary that the preceding entered string is an empty string.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how for example the function `addtext` can be declared and defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N   20

size_t addtext( char ***wordarray )
{
    char word[N];
    const char *sentinel = "end";
    
    size_t n = 0;
    
    int success = 1;
    
    while ( success && scanf( "%19s", word ) == 1 && strcmp( word, sentinel ) != 0 )
    {
        char **tmp = realloc( *wordarray, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char * ) );
        
        success = tmp != NULL;
        
        if ( success )
        {
            ++n;
            *wordarray = tmp;
            ( * wordarray )[n-1] = malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 );
            if ( ( *wordarray )[n-1] ) strcpy( ( *wordarray )[n-1], word );
        }           
    }

    return n;
}   

int main(void) 
{
    char **wordarray = NULL;
    
    size_t n = addtext( &wordarray );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( wordarray[i] != NULL ) puts( wordarray[i] );
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        free( wordarray[i] );
    }
    
    free( wordarray );
    
    return 0;
}
```

If to enter the following sequence of strings

```
one
two
three
end
```

then the program output will be

```
one
two
three
```

Correspondingly the declaration of the function `savetext` should be changed. There is not sense in this case to pass the pointer `wordarray` to the function by reference because the pointer itself is not changed within the function. Also you need to pass the number of elements in the allocated array, So the function declaration can look at least like

```
void savetext( char **wordarray, size_t n );
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps refactor your program to make the string creation its own function, and for symmetry, return storage of the string as its own function.

```
const int STRING_SIZE = 80;
void createString(char ** strPtr, int stringSize);
void freeString(char * strPtr);


int main(int argc, char ** argv)  {
    char * strValue = NULL;

    createString(&strValue, STRING_SIZE);


    // ... do stuff ...

    freeString(strValue);

} 
//
// end of main
//
void createString(char ** strPtr, int stringSize) {
    //
    // uses pass-by-reference to return *strPtr with allocated storage
    //
    *strPtr = (char *) calloc(stringSize, sizeof(char));
}
void freeString(char * strPtr) {
    if(strPtr == NULL) return;
    free(strPtr);
    strPtr = NULL;
}
```